# Hibernate HQL query

Tags: hibernate, hql

I am trying to create HQL query with multiple where paramteres like

```
result = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from County where " + [0].property + "=?"+","+ c[1].property + "=?")
```

.setParameter(0, c[0].value)
.setParameter(1, c[1].value).list();

instead of doing this I am trying to create a query that can handle any number of paramters like

```
for(Params c:parms){`enter code here`
    queryString+= c.property +" = "+c.value+",";
    }
result = (State) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createQuery("from County where " +queryString)
                .list().get(0);
```

There query looks correct but it says "cannot execute query"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) why did you gave up on using a prepared statement like you were with fixed sized parameters?

b) why are you attributing `c.property +" = "+c.value+",";` to "result" instead of to queryString?

c) what is that comma doing on said attribution? Shouldn't it be " and " or " or "?

Re-commenting on your answers

"a) to use multiple pams instead of fixed size"

```
String whereClause = new String();
for (Params p : params) {
    if (whereClause.isEmpty())
        whereClause = " where ";
    else
        whereClause += " and ";
    whereClause += p.property + " = ? ";
}
Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from County " + whereClause);
for (int i = 0; i<params.size(); i++) {
    query.setParameter(i, params[i].value);
}
result = (State) query.list().get(0);
```

"c) even if I have only one param for where using the above code fails! – "

Well yes, even if you have one param you are still adding a comma at the end your query. This is not a valid format

Comment: a) to use multiple pams instead of fixed size b) it should be queryString c) even if I have only one param for where using the above code fails!